# Create generic class with internal constructor

Tags: c#, factory-pattern, generics, object-construction

Is it possible to construct an object with its internal constructor within a generic method?

```
public abstract class FooBase { }

public class Foo : FooBase {
   internal Foo() { }
}

public static class FooFactory {
    public static TFooResult CreateFoo<TFooResult>()
    where TFooResult : FooBase, new() {
        return new TFooResult();
    }
}
```

`FooFactory` resides in the same assembly as `Foo`. Classes call the factory method like this:

```
var foo = FooFactory.CreateFoo<Foo>();
```

They get the compile-time error:

> 'Foo' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TFooType' in the generic type or method 'FooFactory.CreateFoo()'

Is there any way to get around this?

I also tried:

```
Activator.CreateInstance<TFooResult>();
```

This raises the same error at runtime.

Comment: Strangely I don't get any error with your code in .NET 4.  Not sure if this restriction has been relaxed?  Was it a compile-time or run-time error?

Comment: Ah, I'm running .NET 3.5. I'll do some digging. It was a compile-time error.

Comment: In which case, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the `new()` constraint and return:

```
//uses overload with non-public set to true
(TFooResult) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TFooResult), true);
```

although the client could do that too. This, however, is prone to runtime errors.

This is a hard problem to solve in a safe manner since the language does not permit an abstract constructor declaraton.

Comment: I tried that - the same error is just thrown at runtime instead of when compiling.

Comment: @David Neale: Calling the `nonPublic` overload will handle that. Updated.

Comment: Excellent - I didn't see that overload. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The type argument must have a
>   **public** parameterless constructor. When used together with other
>   constraints, the new() constraint must
>   be specified last.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

edit: so no, if you use new() constraint, you cannot pass that class, if you don't use new() constraint you can try using reflection to create new instance

```
public static TFooResult CreateFoo<TFooResult>()
where TFooResult : FooBase//, new()
        {
            return (TFooResult)typeof(TFooResult).GetConstructor(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] {}, null).Invoke(new object[]{});
            //return new TFooResult();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be few work-arounds as below but I don't think you want to go that way!

- Put switch statement inside Factory
  that will create the instance based
  on type of type parameter.
- Each concrete implementation of FooBase will register with FooFactory passing the factory method to create it self. So FooFactory will use the internal dictionary
- Extending on the similar line except mapping between type parameter and concrete implementation would be external code (xml file, configuration etc). IOC/DI containers can also help here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GenericFactory
{
    public static T Create<T>(object[] args)
    {
        var types = new Type[args.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            types[i] = args[i].GetType();

        return (T)typeof(T).GetConstructor(types).Invoke(args);
    }
}
```